# Counter Click Save Cookie

Tags: javascript, button, cookies, counter

I have created a simple counter button with counter show but I don't know how to create a cookie to save the counter.

I would like to save the counter to show to the next user and if the count is "10" when he votes continue with 11

```js
var contador = 1;
var time;
var on = false;
var seconds = 0;


function cambiar() {

  if (seconds >= 10) {
    document.getElementById('contador').innerHTML = contador + 0;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('contador').innerHTML = contador += 1;
  }

}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 4em;
}

#cuadrito {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 00px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #DAA3A3;
}

#contador {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #a3bad8;
}

#boton {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #DAA3A3;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>VOTA BOX</h1>
  <div id="cuadrito">
    <center>
      <div id="contador">0</div>
    </center>
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="boton" value="+1" onClick="cambiar();">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie/Simple_document.cookie_framework

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `document.cookie = 'something'` selector to assign new cookie. I would recommend using HTML5 [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) instead, it's a way more modern solution.

With localstorage, you can use `window.localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')` to set a value in the localstorage and `window.localStorage.getItem('key')` to retrieve it.

Please note that it will not be working properly in the snippet bellow due to the nature of the snippet.

```js
// we retrieve the data from the localstorage, or we default back to 1.
var contador = window.localStorage.getItem('count') || 1;
var time; 
var on = false;
var seconds = 0;


function cambiar()
{
  
  if(seconds >= 10){
    document.getElementById('contador').innerHTML = contador + 0;
  }else{
    document.getElementById('contador').innerHTML = contador += 1;
  }
  
  // we save the count value into the localstorage.
  window.localStorage.setItem('count', contador);
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 4em;
}

#cuadrito{
  width:100px;
  padding:50px;
  margin:00px auto;
  border-radius:10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #DAA3A3;
}

#contador{
    font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #a3bad8;
}
#boton{
  width:100px;
  height:40px;
  border:none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #DAA3A3;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <h1>VOTA BOX</h1>
 <div id="cuadrito"><center>
  <div id="contador">0</div></center>
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="boton" value="+1" onClick="cambiar();">
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in `localStorage` like this:-

```
// set counter key
localStorage.setItem('counter', 10);
// get counter key
var counter = localStorage.getItem('counter');
```